# Laravel: How to merge a Model into another Model

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) to create an API which has to handle 2 entities: `Gamemaster` and `Player`. Both of them are actually a `User` of my API since they have to provide a token. So at the end, 'gamemaster' and 'player' are just an 'user' role.

So I manage them using 3 Models that handle informations from the database (I keep it simple for the example):

- `User`:

  - `id`
  - `username`
  - `email`
  - `password`
- `Gamemaster`:

  - `user_id` (user id as foreign key)
  - `created_games`
  - ...
- `Player`:

  - `user_id` (user id as foreign key)
  - `registered_games`
  - ...

So my question is: Is it possible to merge the Model `User` into `Gamemaster` and `Player`? So that I can for example get a gamemaster email using `Gamemaster::find($id)->email`. Is there any way or I should each time search in both models to get all infos:

```php
$user = User::find($id);
$userAsGamemaster = Gamemaster::where('user_id', '=', $id)->first();

$gamemasterName = $user->username;
$gamemasterEmail = $user->email;
$gamemasterCreatedGame = $userAsGamemaster->created_games;
```

Comment: Not answer to the question of merge two models, but... you can define the relationship in your models and then access to a user model attribute like this `Gamemaster::find($id)->user->email`

Comment: Ok and you can achieve this using @ankurawasthi answers right ? Or is it something else ?

Comment: Yes, Ankur Awasthi's answer is what I suggested in the comment. Just the last code is wrong `Gamemaster::find($id)->email;` should be `Gamemaster::find($id)->user->email`

Comment: So, if in the `$id` variable is the user model id, you should use `$email = Gamemaster::where('user_id', '=', $id)->first()->user->email;`, but if in the `$id` variable is the gamemaster model id you should use `$email = Gamemaster::find($id)->user->email;`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Thanks a lot it's look very clean and seems to be the best practice I presume. If you write it as an answer I will validate it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I write in an answer what we had been talking about in the comments.

Not answer to the question of merge two models, but you can achive what you want defining the relationship in your models Gamemaster and Player:

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

So, if you have the `User` model id in the `$id` variable, you can do something like this:

```
$gamemaster = Gamemaster::where('user_id', $id)->first();

$gamemasterName = $gamemaster->user->username;
$gamemasterEmail = $gamemaster->user->email;
$gamemasterCreatedGame = $gamemaster->created_games;
```

And if in the `$id` variable you have the `Gamemaster` model id, you can do something like this:

```
$gamemaster = Gamemaster::find($id);

$gamemasterName = $gamemaster->user->username;
$gamemasterEmail = $gamemaster->user->email;
$gamemasterCreatedGame = $gamemaster->created_games;
```

And the same for the `Player`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ;) Is this better to use `this->belongsTo(User::class)` rather than `this->belongsTo('App\User')`?

Comment: For this case it is practically the same, neither better nor worse, class resolution (`::class`) it's another way to write it that it is available since PHP 5.5 https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

Answer (score 2):

use relations on model for this.

As in your case Gamemaster and Player both belongs to User so you can define relation on Gamemaster model and Player Model as following: ->

```
public function user(){
  return this->belongsTo('App\User', 'your_foregin_key', 'Your_local_key');
}
```

Now You can fetch email as follows: ->

```
$userAsGamemaster = Gamemaster::where('user_id', '=', $id)->first();
$email = $userAsGamemaster->user->email;
```

Or by using:

```
Gamemaster::find($id)->user->email;
```

That's all.

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ  Thanks for the correction in last line and also for explaining the the concept of id
Important thing is if primary key 'id' than you can use 
   find($id)
else use where('primary_key','=',$id)

Comment: You're welcome. Your answer is good and it have my upvote. I just wrote another answer at the OP's request, that although it is similar to yours has all the explanation for future readers.